# which algorithm should be chosen to complete this task

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

Hi
 I am new to [Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis),I don't know which algorithm is appropriate to my task. let me describe my task:

1. first, given a set of points and their distances between them
2. clustering them into several clusters based on distance.
3. a few new points will be added, the distance among all of points will also be given.
4. repeating 2

for example,first we have the following matrix

```
   | p1 | p2 | p3 |  
---|----|----|----|  
p1 |    |    |    |  
p2 | d1 |    |    |  
p3 | d2 | d3 |    |
```

after clustering, we add a new point and the distance is also given:

```
   | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | 
---|----|----|----|----|  
p1 |    |    |    |    |  
p2 | d1 |    |    |    |  
p3 | d2 | d3 |    |    |  
p4 | d4 | d5 | d6 |    |
```

The problem here is the speed, I expect that the clustering is the incremental cluster, i.e. the later clustering can utilize previous result. Because we will add the points frequently(if we find one), and if we re-cluster the points each time. Even if the cluster itself has O(n), the total time of cluster will be O(n^2).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific on the clustering.  If p1-p2 < d, and p2-p3 < d, but p1-p3 > d, do you still cluster p1,p2,p3 together?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to fix the number of clusters (say, you have K clusters). Whenever you add a new point, you add it to the cluster whose center of gravity (average of the coordinates of the points in the cluster) is nearest to the point you added. If you recluster completely whenever the number of points in your space becomes a power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ...), the amortized cost of reclustering is still O(n).